# Why ant could not find class of listener when I already add jar to lib?

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to add a listener to ant.

> ant -lib /home/victor/parfait-tools-2.3.6/share/parfait-tools/ -listener com.oracle.parfait.ParfaitBuildListener

But it keeps telling me:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Class not found: com.oracle.parfait.ParfaitBuildListener

I don't understand why would that happen because the jar file ParfaitAntTools.jar has contained the class ParfaitBuildListener. How couldn't it be found?

BTW, my ant is 1.9.4

I would appreiciate any help!

Comment: I don't think the listener option accepts wildcards. Try using the full path within the jar.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the asterisk here is used to hide some information about my company by me artificially. Actually I've used full path within both jar and class.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? I am facing same issue.